# Logging network traffic

Tags: networking, wireshark

I would like to log network traffic on my ADSL connection.
The object of this is to see the changes in B/W throughout the day.
I have installed wire-shark and I see that it generates a nice log file which can be exported to CSV.
The problem is I would like to get the length of each packet os that I can anlayze them over time.
This information is not included in the CSV.
Is there a way to expose this in a text file CSV or other format?

Comment: Do you want to do this in code? If not, off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Wireshark exports only the currently displayed columns. By default, the "Packet length" column is hidden. You can show this column by the following steps:

1. Right-click on a column
2. Choose **Column Preferences...** from the context menu
3. Click **Add** from the Preferences dialog
4. In the **Field Type** drop-down, select **Packet length (bytes)**.
5. In the column list, click the title of your new column (default is "New Column") to edit. Change it to "Len" for example.
6. If you wish, you can drag and drop list entries to change the column order (which will be reflected in the exported CSV as well as the GUI).
7. Click **OK**. Now, your exported CSV (**File > Export > as "CSV" file...**) should include packet length.